# Get user details in SocialEngine

Tags: php, socialengine

I want to get user details in **SocialEngine** like we make a plugin in WordPress to get user details. How can I get the user details of the logged in user. I don't want to make any packages or widgets. Also I want to place a script into the head of the SocialEngine. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What is Revolution.Viewer ? I tried it but it is giving me an error saying **'Revolution is not defined'**.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get user info from 'fields_value' and 'users' table.This plugin will be very useful for you http://www.ipragmatech.com/socialapi-rest-socialengine.html .

The plugin have REST API and very useful to integrate socialengine with other CMS or ERP system.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the current viewer or subject within the page through

```
$this->viewer()->getIdentity();
```

The viewer object will give you all the details of the current user viewing the page. You can also call subject with:

```
Engine_Api::_()->core()->getSubject();
```

I cover retrieving the user details in a blog post here:
http://garbtech.co.uk/socialengine-getting-the-current-users-id-and-data

I also discuss creating widgets for user profiles here:
http://garbtech.co.uk/socialengine-creating-widgets-for-user-profiles-getting-the-subject-rather-than-the-viewer-information/